# Solving two quadratic matrix equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given $10 \times 10$ matrices $A$ and $B$, I would like to find $10 \times 10$ matrix $X$ such that

$$A = X B X^T \tag{1}$$

$$B = X A X^T \tag{2}$$

How can I solve the issue? if there is a way to solve only equation (1) or (2) that is ok also.

If anyone can already solve this and show me the way it's fine too.

Matrix $A$:

```
   [[0.125+0.03125i,0,0,0,0,-0.0625,-0.0625,-0.03125,0,0],      
    [0,0.0625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0.15625,0,0,-0.03125i,0,-0.0625,-0.0625],
    [0,0,0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625],
    [-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0],
    [-0.0625,-0.0625,0,-0.03125i,0,0,0.125+0.03125i,0,0,0],
    [-0.03125,0,-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.15625,0,0],
    [0,0,0,-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.0625,0],
    [0,0,0,-0.0625,-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.125]]
```

Matrix $B$:

```
   [[0.15625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625,-0.0625,-0.03125i,0,0],        
    [0,0.0625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0.125+0.03125i,0,0,-0.03125,0,-0.0625,-0.0625],
    [0,0,0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0,-0.0625],
    [-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.0625,0,0,0,0],
    [-0.0625,-0.0625,0,-0.03125,0,0,0.125+0.03125i,0,0,0],
    [-0.03125i,0,-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.09375,0,0],
    [0,0,0,-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.0625,0],
    [0,0,0,-0.0625,-0.0625,0,0,0,0,0.125]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: Since your matrices have complex entries, do you want to transpose or transconjugate?

Comment: X-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4048724

Comment: this is the same question you posted yesterday, https://mathoverflow.net/q/385384/11260 ,  which received some feedback, and which you have now deleted to repost this one; please don't do that, edit a question to improve it, but don't delete and repost.

Comment: The matrices wasn't right, my bad

Comment: transconjugate.

Comment: I am new with the website, i will learn

Comment: Matthew Pilling has already explained that this is impossible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated the determinant of your two matrices:

I find $\det A=7.95808\cdot 10^{-13} \, i$ while $\det B=-4.54747\cdot 10^{-13} + 2.27374\cdot 10^{-13} i$. If your equations (1) and (2) hold, then $\det A=(\det C)^2\det B$ and $\det B=(\det C)^2\det A$, so $(\det A)/(\det B)=(\det B)/(\det A)$, which fails.

Hence there is no solution of both equations $A=XBX^{T}$ and $B=XAX^T$.

---

Now for the solution of a single equation, say $A=XBX^T$. The matrix $X^T$ is the transpose of $X$, so $X_{nm}=X_{mn}$. Both matrices $A$ and $B$ are complex symmetric, $A_{nm}=A_{mn}$ and $B_{nm}=B_{mn}$. Both matrices are also invertible. Then each has a unique complex symmetric square root, $A^{1/2}$ and $B^{1/2}$, see [this MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/376970/11260) . A solution to $A=XBX^T$ is given by
$$X=A^{1/2}B^{-1/2}.$$
The solution is not unique, any matrix $A^{1/2}OB^{-1/2}$ with $O$ real orthogonal (so $OO^T=1$) is also a solution.

I tried this for the matrices $A$ and $B$ listed above, with Mathematica. The output is very lengthy, you can download it from [here](https://www.ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/sqrtasqrtb.txt) and here is the [evidence](https://www.ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/sqrtasqrtb.png) that it works as it should.

---

<sub>The $10\times 10$ matrix in the OP is cumbersome, let me illustrate how this works for a $2\times 2$ matrix:</sub>

$$a=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i & 1 \\
 1 & i \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;b=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
$$a^{1/2}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\sqrt{-1+i}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1+i}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{1+i}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{-1+i}}{2} \\
 \frac{\sqrt{1+i}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{-1+i}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{-1+i}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1+i}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;b^{1/2}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
$$x=a^{1/2}b^{-1/2}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & i \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}} \\
 i \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \\
\end{array}\right),$$

<sub>and you can readily check that $xbx^T=a$. In this particular example the matrix $x$ is symmetric, but in general it is not.</sub>

Comment: Editing Matrix A, there is a possible option that one of the equation will work? (separately). thanks for the help.

Comment: if you want to solve only one of them, that will be possible, but not if by  $X^T$ you mean "transconjugate", as you said in a comment, because $\det A/\det B$ is not real.

Comment: Transpose & Complex Conjugate, its mean that its Transpose(regular) and if there are complex numbers in X , for example i in one of the cells, at XT it will be (-i).

Comment: I am not sure those computations can be trusted. What you see is a very small determinant, of the same magnitude as the machine precision, so it's very well possible that those are both zeros in exact arithmetic and we cannot conclude anything.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni --- I checked that $\det(10\,A)=0.00795808 \,i$ and $\det(10\,B)=-0.00454747 + 0.00227374\, i$, so the difference is not due to lack of accuracy.

Comment: so the only way to solve one equation is with transpose, but not transpose conjugate right? (just to be sure)

Comment: Ok, thanks for help!!

Comment: I am not sure if its really working, I am trying A = XBXT with the X that you wrote here, but I am not receiving the right A

Comment: I See, somehow when I am doing it with python it doesnt give me the same x matrix, what doest the inverse mean in you calculation, can you share with me the sqrt matrix for each matrix, to see that i am receiving the same

Comment: I think the issue is that in python when I am doing **0.5 or sqrt I am getting different results

Comment: ok, i need to figure it out how to do it Python, thanks for the help!

Comment: even if i take x matrix as it is and do x*b*xt i am not getting a

Comment: this must be a programming thing; why don't you first try it in Python on small matrices, then you can check that everything works, before going to the large 10x10 matrix; for the 2x2 case I gave in the answer you can even check it with paper and pencil, so you can be sure your Python code does the right thing.

Comment: I will try the 2x2 matrix, with what tool you did it? (the evidence link)

Comment: with 2x2 matrix there is a small different, I guess its programming thing, I would like to use the tool that you used to reproduce it.

Comment: I used a commercial piece of software (Mathematica), but there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to do it in Python.

Comment: As i said in 2x2 matrix there was a small deviation, so i cant count on the python

Comment: Ok, I used also Mathematica and I got similar results to you, all the zero cells are x10(-16)-(-18) that is equivalent to zero. thanks for the help!