# Questions regarding answer to complex symmetric square root of a complex symmetric invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

I am looking at showing that a complex symmetric invertible matrix always has a complex symmetric square root and I refer to [this Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438232/497608) for the answer to this question. I am little confused at the reasoning given in the answer however, specifically in two places.

1. Firstly, how can we show that the polynomial $Q(z) := P(z)^2 -z$ and its $m_j-1$ derivatives are all $0$ at each $\lambda_j$? I have done out a the first few examples which all work, but how do we know this in general? Note that $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of some $n \times n$ complex matrix $A$ and $m_j$ are the indices of $\lambda_j$ in the Jordan Canonical Form of $A$.
2. Once we have established the result in (1) above, the answer to the OP says that this implies that $Q(z)$ is a multiple of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, denoted here by $C_A(z)$.

My understanding for (2) is this: For $Q(z)$ and $C_A(z)$ to be a multiplicative constant, they both must have the same roots and these roots must have the same multiplicities. Both $C_A(z)$ and $Q(z)$ have $\lambda_j$ as their roots, this is obvious. Initially, I thought that the derivatives of $Q(z)$ up to order $m_j-1$ being $0$ implied something about the multiplicities of each of the roots but now I don't think that is true because the multiplicity and the index aren't necessarily the same.

Since then I have hit a bit of a wall. Does anyone have any insight into these two problems?

Comment: if $A$ is invertible the logarithm of $A$ exists, and a square root is $e^{\tfrac{1}{2}\log A}$; this is symmetric because $(e^B)^\top=e^{B^\top}$ and $(\log A)^\top=\log A^\top$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$

1. Let $g(z)$ denote some branch of $\sqrt z$, so that $Q(z)=P(z)^2-g(z)^2$ and $P^{(k)}(\la_j)=g^{(k)}(\la_j)$ for each $j$ and all $k=0,\dots,m_j-1$, where the $\la_j$'s are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and the $m_j$'s are their multiplicities. Then, by the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), $Q^{(k)}(\la_j)=0$ for each $j$ and all $k=0,\dots,m_j-1$.
2. So, for some polynomial $R(z)$,
   \begin{equation}
       Q(z)=R(z)\prod_j(z-\la_j)^{m_j}
   =R(z)C(z), \tag{1}\label{1}
   \end{equation}
   where $C(z):=\prod_j(z-\la_j)^{m_j}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (see details on the first equality in \eqref{1} below). So, the polynomial $Q(z)$ is indeed a multiple of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

(The [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438232/36721), referred to in your question, does not even mention indices.)

---

**Details on the first equality in \eqref{1}:**

> **Lemma 1:** Let $q(z)$ be a polynomial such that $q^{(k)}(\la)=0$ for some $\la$ and all $k=0,\dots,m-1$, where $m$ is an integer $\ge1$. Then $(z-\la)^m$ is a divisor of the polynomial $q(z)$ -- that is,
> $q(z)=(z-\la)^m S(z)$ for some polynomial $S(z)$.

*Proof of Lemma 1:* By shifting, without loss of generality $\la=0$.
Divide $q(z)$ by $z^m$ with a remainder $r(z)$ of degree $\le m-1$, so that $q(z)=z^m s(z)+r(z)$ for some polynomial $s(z)$. Then for all $k=0,\dots,m-1$ we have $0=q^{(k)}(0)=r^{(k)}(0)$. Because $r(z)$ is of degree $\le m-1$, it follows that $r(z)$ is the zero polynomial, so that $q(z)=z^m s(z)$, which completes the proof of Lemma 1. $\quad\Box$

Now, by part 1 of the answer, $Q^{(k)}(\la_j)=0$ for each $j$ and all $k=0,\dots,m_j-1$. So, for each $j$, by Lemma 1, the polynomial $(z-\la_j)^{m_j}$ is a divisor of the polynomial $Q(z)$. Also,  the polynomials $(z-\la_j)^{m_j}$ are coprime for different values of $j$, since the $\la_j$'s are distinct. So, $\prod_j(z-\la_j)^{m_j}$ is a divisor of $Q(z)$; that is, the first equality in \eqref{1} holds.

It remains to provide

Comment: Thank you for your help in answering these questions. I now fully understand the issue raised in part 1. I have some questions on part 2 though and I don't know if I should "ask a new question" or just write each of them in their own comment in this section? I would like to include my own thoughts and I don't know if the allowable space here is conducive to that? On the other hand, maybe it is better to keep them all together? What do people think?

Comment: @jcb2535 : I suggest you just tell me what still seems unclear about part 2. If doing this requires a substantial write-up, perhaps you can create a link to it.

Comment: I will write a short version of the questions here and see if it suffices. 1. Why is $n_j \geq m_j$? How can we know this for certain? 2. We obtain that $\lambda_j$ are the roots of $Q(z)$ but why do we need to show that the derivatives of $Q(t)$ equal 0 at each $\lambda_j$ for this? Is showing that $Q(\lambda_j) = 0$ for each $\lambda_j$ not enough? 3. Where does $R(z)$ come from? Since we know the roots and multiplicities of $Q(z)$, shouldn't $R(z)$ not be a constant instead of a polynomial?

Comment: @jcb2535 : I have added the requested details.

Comment: @jcb2535 : Do you have a further response?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, I was trying to process the answers above. 1) In lemma 1, should it not be $q(z) = (z-\lambda)^n S(z)$? This would match the $Q(z) = R(Z)..$ in the OP. 2) I don't understand your reasoning here. You take 0 as an eigenvalue with multiplicity 2 and then give a polynomial where this is not true? 3) Why is the $R(z)$ in in the last line of your explanation? If for $j = 1, ..., s$, you know the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ and multiplicities $m_j$ of some polynomial $Q(z)$, then is it not true that $Q(z) = (z-\lambda_1)^{m_1} .......  (z-\lambda_s)^{m_s}$? No need for the $R(z)$.

Comment: A better explanation of my confusion with $R(z)$ is that I don't know how it can be a polynomial. If $\lambda_j$ are all the roots of $Q(z)$ with multiplicities $n_j$, then is it not true that $Q(z) = \prod_{j} (z - \lambda_j)^{n_j}$. If $R(z)$ is another polynomial that is not a constant, then you have changed $Q(Z)$ to be a polynomial with the same roots and multiplicities as before but now with the extra roots and multiplicities of $R(z)$?

Comment: @jcb2535 : I can hardly understand your penultimate comment. In particular, I don't know what $Z$ there is. Also, I never had "multiplicity 2" in my answer. As for your latter comment, again: Whether $R(z)$ is a constant or not is irrelevant to the proof -- we just need $R(z)$ to be a polynomial; remember: a constant is a polynomial as well, of degree $0$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Anyhow, I do not want to repeat that anymore. Instead, I have tried to simplify the proof, at the same time providing more details. If anything is still unclear, just let me know what is the **first** logical transition that is unclear to you. Try not to ask me **why I did or did not do something** (sometimes, this is hard or impossible to explain). Instead, ask me only **why a logical conclusion is true** (if you have doubts about it).

Comment: Firstly, I apologise for the structure/content of my comments, after re-reading I can see why you found them difficult to read. Secondly, thank you for your patience and advice and I understand the points you made in your comments. Thirdly, the proof you have kindly provided above is very clear and I understand it. My only request is for a reference for the lemma you provided.

Comment: @jcb2535 : This lemma is most probably well known and can be found in many textbooks. However, I don't have a ready reference now. This is a case, for me, when it is much easier to prove something than to find it in the literature.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis : OK great! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

This technique of computing matrix functions via interpolating polynomials is described in more detail in Chapter 1 of this book.

*Higham, Nicholas J.*, [**Functions of matrices. Theory and computation**](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898717778), Philadelphia, PA: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (SIAM) (ISBN 978-0-898716-46-7/hbk; 978-0-89871-777-8/ebook). xx, 425 p. (2008). [ZBL1167.15001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1167.15001).

I suggest you check it out if you are interested in knowing more; the same chapter has also more insight on the different square roots that can be defined for a matrix.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes it is a very good book for this topic. The explanations are clear and they give some examples which really helps with understanding.